# How to tell a page to load a JS function based on variables being sent

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a function which loads some content when executed...

IE...

```
function load_product(product_id) {

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'product_image.php',
  data: 'product_id='+product_id+'',
  success: function(data) {
        $('#product_image').html(data);
  }
});
}
```

That works great. But say I want to create a link to a page, so that then something triggers to load up the dynamic content?

IE I link to a page, say

```
www.blah.com/?product=1
```

and a few 'divs' on the page that load up different things dynamically for product #1.

The way I currently do it is by doing something:

```
<?php

  if($_REQUEST['product_id']) {

    echo '

     <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

           load_product(' . $_REQUEST['product_id'] . ');

        });

     </script>

      ';

  }
```

And I put that somewhere on the new page being loaded. It works. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar but using [YepNope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/).

```
<script>
var hasProduct = <?php echo isset($_REQUEST['product']) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>

yepnope({
    test : hasProduct,
    yep  : 'js_file_to_load.js',
});
</script>
```

Then you can store all you main js in an external file. This has the added advantage over your method in that, I don't have to load the external scripts for every request just in case `$_REQUEST['product']` is set.

Comment: It's a great little library that weighs in at about 1.6kb so it's completely worth it. You can even speed up page load times but executing an ajax call on page load, that return a json object of all the scripts you need to load for that page, and then use yepnope to load them. This way the page can render without any excess javascripts that aren't needed to make the page viewable like jQuery UI widgets. Flickr use a similar technique with YUI modules.

Comment: So currently all my JS functions are in the 1 file. With this sort of solution, one would split it into appropriate sections.... say a backend I have made has many different pages.. I would basically split the JS file into a script for each page and use yepnope to load the relevant resources. I'm wondering if this is more useful for larger libraries than smaller ones... ie the function above is only a few hundred bytes so to load it inline like this is going to be less than loading an additional library right?

Comment: When things are small like that you might be able to justify keeping things inline. But I would recommend a solution like this for many reason: Scalability - one small file now becomes one big file later, if you start using this solution early you can avoid headaches later. Speed - loading smaller files is simply faster (this can be negated by extra requests but this is easily solved with combining files in production). Maintainability - code is nice and easier to work with (and debug) when separated logically into smaller files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in JavaScript.
Use 'location.search' to give you the query part of the current URL...
for example, if the url is "www.blah.com/?product=1" then location.search returns "?product=1".  Then you can just use split('=') to get part number.  Of course, you can also just get the whole URL using 'location.href'... doesn't really matter.

```
var productNum = parseInt(location.search.split('=')[1]);
```

You would probably want more checks in there, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: thats really handy. so its getting the number from the url. similar to the yepno function but less code?